# How to set textarea value with line break in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, textarea, line-breaks

I have this ReactJS component

```
  class Header extends Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <div>
             <textarea class="editTextarea" value={this.props.header}></textarea>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }
```

for which i would like to show line breaks.

If i use br tag,\n,\r .. i cannot see line breaks

```
   <Header header="Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4"></Header>
```

results:

[image]

How can i set a string to show line breaks in textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&#13;` for line breaks in html:

```
 <Header header="Line1&#13;Line2&#13;Line3&#13;Line4"></Header>
```